# how to stop program from terminating itself after chosing option 5

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes

I am making a function of inserting a node at a specific position in a linked list.

Everything is running fine except for option 5) inserting at a specific position and 9) Display.

If I choose 5), the program asks for a number. After providing a number, it terminates on its own.

Similarly, when I choose 9), the program shows the data in the node and then terminates, yet I have put in a `while` loop for stoppage.

My main file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int value, count, value2, count2;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node * next;
};

node *list = nullptr;
node * p;
node * q;
node * r;

void insertFront()
{
    cout << "ENTER A VALUE=";
    cin >> value;

    if (list == nullptr)
    {
        p = new node();
        p->data = value;
        p->next = nullptr;
        list = p;
    }
    else
    {
        p = new node();
        p->data = value;
        p->next = list;
        list = p;
    }
}

void display()
{
    p = list;
    while (p != nullptr)
    {
        cout << p->data << " ";
        p = p->next;
    }

    cout << p->data << endl;
}

void insertSpec()
{
    cout << "Enter the number after which you want to enter a node=";
    cin >> value;

    if (list == nullptr && value > 1)
    {
        cout << "THERE IS NO OTHER NODE SO YOU CANNOT PUT A NODE AT " << value;
    }

    if (list != nullptr && value > 0)
    {
        cout << "ENTER THE NUMBER YOU WANT TO ENTER=";
        cin >> value2;
        count = 1;
        count2 = 1;
        while (count != (value))
        {
            p = p->next;
            count++;
        }

        while (count2 != (value + 1))
        {
            q = q->next;
            count2++;
        }

        r = new node();
        r->data = value2;
        p->next = r;
        r->next = q;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "1) Insert at front" << endl;
    cout << "5) Insert at specified place" << endl;
    cout << "9) Display" << endl << endl;
    while (choice != 99)
    {
        cout << "Your choice:";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            {
                insertFront();
                break;
            }
        case 5:
            {
                insertSpec();
                break;
            }
        case 9:
            {
                display();
                break;
            }
        case 99:
            {
                cout << "PROGRAM TERMINATED :)";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Any chance you could cut the code down to the bit that really matters?  (See [mre]). Also, I agree with @nathan

Comment: I cant write the code in comments but you can just check display() and insertSpec(). After putting a value to a node using insertFront() when i call display the program displays and terminates itself but i have used while loop still it terminates

Comment: You are intended to [edit] your question, not put code in comments.

Comment: Consider, what is the value of `p` and `q` when you first call `insertSpec`?  Why are `p`, `q`, and `r` global (or `value`, `count`, `value2` and `count2` for that matter)?

Comment: And why are the variables `p`, `q`, and `r` anyway? What useful information do those names contain? If the answer is little or none, give them better, more descriptive names. You'll thank yourself later.

Comment: Unrelated: In `insertFront()` you have `if (list == nullptr) { ...; p->next = nullptr; } else { ...; p->next = list; }`  so why not just remove everything but the `else` block? If `list == nullptr`, then `p->next = list;` will assign `nullptr` to `p->next` anyway. You could even simplify the whole thing to `list = new node{value, list};`.

Answer (score 1):

In `insertSpec()`, the 1st loop has *undefined behavior* if the user's specified node number is past the end of the list, and the 2nd loop has *undefined behavior* because `q` is never assigned to point at a valid `node`.

`display()` has *undefined behavior* when it tries to access `p->data` after the loop is finished because `p` is `nullptr` by then.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next = nullptr;
};

node *list = nullptr;

void insertFront()
{
    int value;

    cout << "ENTER A VALUE=";
    cin >> value;

    list = new node{value, list};
}

void display()
{
    for(node *p = list; p != nullptr; p = p->next)
    {
        cout << p->data << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void insertSpec()
{
    int number, value;

    cout << "Enter the node number after which you want to enter a new node=";
    cin >> number;
    
    if (number < 1)
    {
        cout << "INVALID NODE NUMBER!" << endl;
        return;
    }

    node **p = &list;
    int n = number;

    while (*p != nullptr && n > 0)
    {
        p = &((*p)->next);
        --n;
    }

    if (n > 0)
    {
        cout << "YOU CANNOT PUT A NODE AFTER " << number << endl;
        return;
    }

    cout << "ENTER THE VALUE YOU WANT TO ADD=";
    cin >> value;

    *p = new node{value, *p};
}

int main()
{
    int choice;

    cout << "1) Insert at front" << endl;
    cout << "5) Insert at specified place" << endl;
    cout << "9) Display" << endl;
    cout << "99) Exit" << endl << endl;

    do
    {
        cout << "Your choice:";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            insertFront();
            break;

        case 5:
            insertSpec();
            break;

        case 9:
            display();
            break;
        }
    }
    while (choice != 99);

    cout << "PROGRAM TERMINATED :)";

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/wxaW4q)

Answer (score 0):

Well for the two problems:

1. Display function: If we track the code, we will notice the problem here:
   Assume the list contained: 123

   ```
   void display()
   {
       p = list; // will point to the 1
       while (p != nullptr)
       {
           cout << p->data << " "; //printing: 1:2:3
           p = p->next;// p point to: 2:3:NULL
       }
       cout << p->data << endl;
       // Basically p here is pointing to null so this statement is causing the problem if you removed this cout the code will run fine.
       cout<<endl; // Use only
   }
   ```
2. For the `insertSpec` function:

First thing you need to declare `p` and `q` and set their values:

> ```
> p = list;
> q = list;
> ```
>
> More thing to be considered I prefer if you a variable to have the
> length of the list .... the main reason is to validate the indexes
> with the length.
> if you need any help or faced any problem you can ask any time.
> Hope this was helpful.